# Can we access protected member functions of base class in derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, radix, derived

As i have studied that **Derived class can access protected member of base class. In derived class, protected member of base class works as public in derived class.** But when i implement this , i get a error

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

class Shape {
   protected :
      void setWidth(int w) {
         width = w;
      }
      void setHeight(int h) {
         height = h;
      }
      
   protected:
      int width;
      int height;
};

// Derived class
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
      int getArea() { 
         return (width * height); 
      }
};

int main(void) {
   Rectangle Rect;
 
   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);

   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
In function ‘int main()’:
32:19: error: ‘void Shape::setWidth(int)’ is protected within this context
    Rect.setWidth(5);
                   ^

:9:12: note: declared protected here
       void setWidth(int w) {
            ^~~~~~~~
:33:20: error: ‘void Shape::setHeight(int)’ is protected within this context
    Rect.setHeight(7);
                    ^
:12:12: note: declared protected here
       void setHeight(int h) {
            ^~~~~~~~~
```

Please somebody help me to understand the Access modifiers

Comment: `Rectangle::setWidth()` is not `public`, but you're trying to access it as if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the derived class can access protected members, whether those members are data or functions. But in your code, it's `main` which is attempting to access `setWidth` and `setHeight`, not `Rectangle`. That's invalid just like using `width` and `height` from `main` would be.

An example of the derived class using the protected member functions:

```
class Rectangle: public Shape {
public:
    int getArea() const { 
        return (width * height); 
    }
    void setDimensions(int w, int h) {
        setWidth(w);
        setHeight(h);
    }
};
```

Or if you really want `Rectangle` to let anyone else use the functions, you can use the access `Rectangle` has to make them `public` members of `Rectangle` instead of `protected`:

```
class Rectangle: public Shape {
public:
    using Shape::setWidth;
    using Shape::setHeight;

    int getArea() const { 
        return (width * height); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> **In derived class, protected member of base class works as public in derived class.**

That is not true. Either your source is wrong, or this quote is taken out of relevant context.

Protected members of publicly-inherited base class are, by default, still protected in the derived class, meaning, the derived class member functions can access them, but they are not accessible from outside of the class.

You can confirm it and learn more details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access), specifically in the "Protected member access" paragraph.